# PHP search engine Notice: Undefined index: category

Tags: php, search-engine

Hi guys I have made a script with some help who browse in a category
Example: We have next categorie PCgames, All and Documents. X user is searching in PCgames for Y game. And the script is saerching in PCgames ategory for Y game and display the all results.
But when the user click on search button the server display next error Notice: Undefined index: category in search.php on line 5
HTML code

```
    <form action="search.php" method="POST">
<p><br />
<input name="q" type="hidden" />
<font color="black">Hunt Data:</font>
<input type="text" style="width: 180px" name="qfront" id="name" />
<select name="category">
<option value="0" id="all">All</option>
<option value="1" id="PCgames">PC-Games</option>
<option value="2" id="Console">Console</option>
<option value="3" id="Movies">Movies</option>
<option value="4" id="Music">Music</option>
<option value="5" id="XXX">XXX</option>
<option value="6" id="Windows">Windows</option>
<option value="7" id="Linux">Linux</option>
<option value="8" id="Software">Software</option>
<option value="9" id="Documents">Documents</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</p>
</form>
```

search.php file

```
    <?php
//define each directory here, the index starts with 0 == all and so on.
$categorydir = array('/Category/All/', '/Category/PCGames/', '/Category/Documents/');
//if option selected and its valid number
if($_POST['category'] && ctype_digit($_POST['category'])){    //line 5
 if(array_key_exists($_POST['category'], $categorydir) && is_dir($categorydir[$_POST['category']])){
   $handle = opendir($categorydir[$_POST['category']]);
 }else{
   echo 'target directory not found';
 }
}else{
 //please enter an option
}
?>
```

Some help for Notice: Undefined index: category in search.php on line 5 ?

Comment: Try `if (isset($_POST['category']) ...)` instead.

Comment: Try improving your original post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056015/php-search-function-in-a-category It can be reopened if you do so.

Comment: Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in search.php on line 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['category']) {
 if(ctype_digit($_POST['category']) && isset($categorydir[$_POST['category']])){

 }
}
```

and your array

```
 $categorydir = array('/Category/All/', '/Category/PCGames/', '/Category/Documents/');
```

have 3 entries, though your form have 10 cats.

Comment: Thanks man. This script is working but he don`t display the results...